# Multiple files with same date but different hours in the same dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have to read multiple files that are in different directories and then put them in the same dataframe. I'm using a csv file to read the dates.

The files names are organized as hgyymmddhhhhh

yy=year

mm=month

dd=day

hhhh=hour

The thing is: For the same day, I can have either 1, 2 or 3 different hours:

hg1308250000.nc

hg1308250100.nc

hg1308250200.nc

or

hg1309201100.nc

hg1309201200.nc

or

hg1310281300.nc

The script I made is reading only one hour per day...If the day has 2 or 3 different hours, it is just ignoring it. For the 25th of August, for example, It is only reading hg1308250200.nc

```
 df=pd.read_csv('/home/Desktop/dates.csv')
         df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)


       df['year'], df['month'], df['day'] = df['Date'].dt.year.map(" 
        {:02}".format), df['Date'].dt.month.map("{:02}".format), 
        df['Date'].dt.day.map("{:02}".format)

       df['year2']=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%y')


      for p in np.arange(len(df)):
              year=str(df.iloc[p,1])
              month=str(df.iloc[p,2])
              day=str(df.iloc[p,3])
              year2=str(df.iloc[p,4])

              os.chdir('/home/Documents/PhD/Data/'+year+'/DWD/' 
              +month+ '/')       
              for file in glob.glob('hg' +year2+ month+ day +'*.nc'):
                 data1 = Dataset(file, 'r')
                 data1.set_auto_mask(False)
                 hour= str(file[8:12])
          
             errorbc = data1.variables['ErrorBackscatter'][:]
             bc = data1.variables['Backscatter'][:
             alt = data1.variables['Altitude'][:]
                      
             df_final = pd.DataFrame({'bc': bc, 'bc_e': errorbc, 
             'hour':hour}, index=alt)
             df_final = df_final.assign(date=df.iloc[p].Date)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this in order to get all the files from the same day in the dataframe?

Comment: are you able to show us your sample data and expected output? we can help then and also see if your code is optimal.

Comment: The answer I got down here helped a lot! Exactly what I was looking for! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inconsistent whitespace is making the code a bit hard to read, but it looks like the final 6 lines of code are outside the `for` loop, but use variables from inside it. In that case, they'll use the last assigned values, which according to your example would be "0200" for the hour on August 25th.

To fix that, make the dictionary you use for `df_final` inside the for loop and save it to a list, then do the final concatenation outside.

```
list_of_dataframes = []
for file in glob.glob('hg' +year2+ month+ day +'*.nc'):
    data1 = Dataset(file, 'r')
    data1.set_auto_mask(False)
    hour = file[8:12]

    errorbc = data1.variables['ErrorBackscatter'][:]
    bc = data1.variables['Backscatter'][:]
    alt = data1.variables['Altitude'][:]

    df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'bc': bc, 'bc_e': errorbc, 'hour':hour})
    list_of_dataframes.append(df_temp)

df_final = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
df_final.index = alt
df_final = df_final.assign(date=df.iloc[p].Date)
```